# Golang templates: using strings with variable slots in printf

Tags: go, templates

I'm trying to fill in a simple box in a golang template with the content "you've finished part x of y" where X is the index of the loop and Y is the total length of the items.

The problem is that golang template is handling multiple languages.  So, for example, you wouldn't be able to do this:

```
{{ printf "you've finished part %d of %d" $index $totalLength }}
```

This doesn't work because the part "you've finished part...of..." is in multiple languages loaded with the page, and is stored in a variable.

My attempt is thus:

```
{{with $translatedText := getTranslatedText "textID"}} {{printf $translatedText $index $totalLength}}{{end}}
```

In the above example, $translatedText is "You've finished part %d of %d," a string with two arguments for me to fill. Typed out, this works.  Stored in a variable, it does not.

This is resulting in the too many arguments error: "%!(EXTRA int=0, int=3)"

When I print out index and totallength by themselves, they parse. How do I get the text of $translatedText into a raw string form so I can printf it with variables?

Comment: Your example works, try it out here: https://go.dev/play/p/bbQc_Xk4GZd Unless I misunderstood something.